# Why do my WebDriverWaits error after 1 second when they are set for 20 seconds?

Tags: webdriverwait

I have multiple WebDriverWaits in my tests, all of the format you can see below, but they very often fail after only a second or two, even though theyu should poll for the element every half second for 20 seconds - can anyone tell me what I'm missing please?:

```
{
private static By pageTitle = By.XPath(".//*[@id='wm-page-title']/h1");

public static void WaitForPageLoad()
{
 var waitForPageLoad = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, enter code 
 hereTimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
 var myPageLoadElement = waitForPageLoad.Until(ElementIsVisible(pageTitle));
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry code didn't paste properly:

Comment: Code shoudl have read:

Comment: public static void WaitForPageLoad()
  {
   var waitForPageLoad = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
   var myPageLoadElement = waitForPageLoad.Until(ElementIsVisible(pageTitle));
  }